# Getting error Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am trying to set a recycler View in android but the adapter class is giving me error as mentioned in the title. I searched and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30799956/attempt-to-invoke-virtual-method-void-android-widget-textview-settextjava-lang). The answers here say that there is a mismatch in the naming. I checked my names but am still getting the error.

Here is adapter:

```
public class RecyclerViewAdapter3 extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewAdapter3.ViewHolder> {

Context context3;
List<ImageUploadInfo> MainImageUploadInfoList;


public RecyclerViewAdapter3(Context context, List<ImageUploadInfo> TempList) {

    this.MainImageUploadInfoList = TempList;

    this.context3 = context;
}

public RecyclerViewAdapter3.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.recyclerview_items, parent, false);

    ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(view);

    return viewHolder;
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {

    return MainImageUploadInfoList.size();
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final RecyclerViewAdapter3.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    ImageUploadInfo UploadInfo = MainImageUploadInfoList.get(position);

    holder.imageNameTextView.setText(UploadInfo.getImageName());

    Uri uri = Uri.parse(UploadInfo.getImageURL());
    Log.d("TAGGG" , ""+uri);
    holder.userText.setText(uri.toString());
}

class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public TextView imageNameTextView ;
    public TextView userText;


    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        userText = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView13);

        imageNameTextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.caption);
    }
}
}
```

Here is the xml file which the recycler will inflate(items3):

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="303dp"
    android:layout_height="378dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    app:cardElevation="20dp"
    app:cardCornerRadius="20dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView13"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="327dp"
            android:text="TextView" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/caption"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/aguafina_script"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:hint="Caption"
            android:textColor="@color/common_google_signin_btn_text_dark_focused"
            android:textSize="26sp" />
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Here is the log:

```
Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
    at com.avalonglobalresearch.creatives.RecyclerViewAdapter3.onBindViewHolder(RecyclerViewAdapter3.java:50)
    at com.avalonglobalresearch.creatives.RecyclerViewAdapter3.onBindViewHolder(RecyclerViewAdapter3.java:14)
```

ImageUploadInfo:

```
public class ImageUploadInfo {

    public String imageName;

    public String imageURL;

    public ImageUploadInfo() {

    }

    public ImageUploadInfo(String name, String url) {

        this.imageName = name;
        this.imageURL= url;
    }

    public String getImageName() {
        return imageName;
    }

    public String getImageURL() {
        return imageURL;
    }
    }
```

Please show me where I am going wrong.

Comment: post `ImageUploadInfo` model. My best guess :- `UploadInfo.getImageName()` **returns some type other than** `String`. **Make the method return string.**

Answer (score 2):

Ok so I found the problem, I was inflating the wrong xml file. `View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.recyclerview_items, parent, false);`
Here instead of inflating `items3.xml` , I was inflating `recyclerview_items` due to which I was getting the error.

Thank you everyone for helping me and sorry for wasting your times

Answer (score 1):

```
public class RecyclerViewAdapter3 extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewAdapter3.ViewHolder> {

Context context3;
List<ImageUploadInfo> MainImageUploadInfoList;


public RecyclerViewAdapter3(Context context, List<ImageUploadInfo> TempList) {

this.MainImageUploadInfoList = TempList;

this.context3 = context;
}

public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.recyclerview_items, parent, false);

ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(view);

return viewHolder;
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {

return MainImageUploadInfoList.size();
 }

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
ImageUploadInfo UploadInfo = MainImageUploadInfoList.get(position);

holder.imageNameTextView.setText(UploadInfo.getImageName());

Uri uri = Uri.parse(UploadInfo.getImageURL());
Log.d("TAGGG" , ""+uri);
holder.userText.setText(""+uri.toString());
}

class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
public TextView imageNameTextView ;
public TextView userText;


public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
    super(itemView);

    userText = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView13);

    imageNameTextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.caption);
   }
}
```

check xml file name too

Comment: The uri is correct , and im still getting that error

Answer (score 1):

use this :

> holder.userText.setText(uri.toString()+"");

this can handle any datatype valu

Answer (score 1):

In your `onBindViewHolder` try to cast the holder to `ViewHolder`

```java
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final RecyclerViewAdapter3.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    ViewHolder holderView = (ViewHolder)holder; // <-- Cast the ViewHolder

    ImageUploadInfo UploadInfo = MainImageUploadInfoList.get(position);

    holderView.imageNameTextView.setText(UploadInfo.getImageName());  // <-- use holderView instead of holder

    Uri uri = Uri.parse(UploadInfo.getImageURL());
    Log.d("TAGGG" , ""+uri);
    holderView.userText.setText(uri.toString());   // <-- use holderView instead of holder
}
```